# How to get the GUID for BrandingThemeID

Tags: guid

We need the BrandingThemeID GUID so we can pass it using the API, but how do you see what the GUID is please?

Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8DfU.png)

We opened the Branding Themes but cannot see the GUID. Xero doesnt seem to show the GUID anywhere.